# Get data from a mongodbdump.tar GZ file onto a localhost db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, tar, gzip, mongorestore

I am looking to make a new db on my localhost from a mongodbdump file. the file looks like this:

`C:\Users\ME\FILEPATH\database\somedata-mongodbdump.tar.gz`

How can I use mongo shell commands to "restore" this data to a new db on my local host? I know how to set up a new DB and insert records no problem, but I am not sure how to unload this data into one.

I am not finding anything in my searches or the documentation as to how to straightforwardly do this.

I'd like to get this file into a DB that I can host locally and use as the back end for testing an app.

Answer (score 1):

I was misguided here and the previous answers is incorrect. While it may be pretty beginner stuff for some people, I will answer my own question in case anyone else runs into this:

A `.tar.gz` file is effectively a double zipped file. For Mongo, we need a `.bson` file. Unzip the file with 7zip or through CMD.

Once you have the BSON in a directory, in CMD (not mongo shell) type:

`mongorestore --db 'yourdbname' --collection 'yourcollectionname' C\filepath\filepath\filename.bson`

Answer (score 0):

use  [mongo restore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)

```
mongorestore -u 'user' -p 'password -d 'database' -c 'collection' 'path to file'
```

if you are using a different database for auth then add 
--authenticationDatabase='db for auth'